# Using fadeIn fadeOut on setTimeout?

Tags: jquery, settimeout, fadein, fadeout

Can I use a fadeIn or fadeOut on a setTimeout? I have 3 background images in an array and I want to fade each one in slowly.

This is my code that works fine, I would just like the transition to be slow rather than super quick as it is now.

```
$(function () {
var nextImage = $('.main-background');
var backgrounds = [
  'url(<?= $image_url ?>/big-main-background-1.jpg)', 
  'url(<?= $image_url ?>/big-main-background-2.jpg)', 
  'url(<?= $image_url ?>/big-main-background-3.jpg)'];

var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
    nextImage.css(
        'background',
    backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);

    setTimeout(nextBackground, 4000);
}
setTimeout(nextBackground, 4000);
nextImage.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
});
```

Comment: I don't think you can fade backgrounds by css. But you can do it by using multiple actual images stacking on each other and changing their opacity.

Comment: Meaning what, on image 1 (opacity is 1) and image 2 and image 3 (opacity 0). Then when image 2 shows the Opacity is 1 and for image 1 and image 3 opacity goes to 0. Something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3xdzxpmh/1/

Here's a different approach, you can feel free to ask if you have any question.

Just replace the style or the content with the background of yours.

If you want to apply this to your container, insert the following structure into your main container and max out it's width and height.

Here's the structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="background:red"></div>
    <div style="background:yellow"></div>
    <div style="background:blue"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the JS I've modified from your code:

```
var current = 0;
$(function(){
    var l = $(".container div").length;
    change();
    function change() {
        current = ++current % l;
        $(".container div").removeClass("show");
        $(".container div:nth-child("+(current+1)+")").addClass("show");
        setTimeout(change,2000);
    }
});
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.container {
    position:relative;
}

.container > div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    transition:1s all ease;
}

.container > div.show {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Basically, the CSS class `.show` states that the element must be opaque. The `.container div` sets a style of **transparent and has a transition.** When `.show` is toggled, **2 `<div>` fade together, creating the effect**.

Comment: ok give me a few minutes to try this out. I'm going to have to modify all my HTML because inside my main div I have other divs with text and this code you provided would be calling my divs with text and h1 tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery function [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/), you can specify duration there.